# Does my generator interlock require a ground rod?

Tags: grounding, generator, neutral

I will back feed the main panel of my home with the portable generator, power inlet box and breaker. The schematic for the generator shows that neutral is connected to the ground inside the generator.

The power inlet box has a neutral connection that connects in the panel.

The generator is a DuroMax XP10000EH 10,000-Watt 439cc Electric Start Dual Fuel Hybrid Portable Generator.

Do I require a ground rod in this setup? Also does the neutral inside the generator need to be removed for this configuration?

Thanks for the fast response. I have an interlock kit on the way already. Just to be clear. Once I remove the neutral to ground connection in my portable generator setup, for my setup I will still not need a ground rod connected to the ground post of the generator. The ground connected through the inlet box which connects to the panel ground serves as the generator ground?

Comment: What make and model is your generator?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need an interlock between the utility main breaker and the generator backfeed breaker.   That is a must - don't skip it.  We can help figure out anything around setting that up.

Second, yes -- you need to have *exactly one* neutral-ground bond in the entire system.  Your main panel already has that.   So if your generator connects neutral and ground internally, that must be disconnected.  This is a threat to your system at all times when the generator is plugged in - not just when you're on generator.

This will need to be reconnected if you use the generator as a "portable" (i.e. take it on the road to use the outlets for convenience power).